# Is there a way to render a wireframe independent of its topology?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, wireframe

Lets say I have an object and I want to render it in squarish wireframe in orthographic view. Here is what I mean - 
[image]

I am not looking for a specific topology in the 3d view, but what ever the topology of a model is, is it possible to render it in this way? I know that there are tricks to do this, for example by using chroma key, but as you can see in the image it is not acurate because it has picked up information from the original black background. Is there any way to do this in blender without the usage of chroma key?

Update - Basically, to render an object independent of its topology with a checkered wireframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: nodes]
The *Brick* texture node makes the grid texture.
The settings to change in the *Brick* texture node are:

- both *Frequency* fields, set to 1
- *brick width* and *Row height* must match to get squares.
- *Mortar size* to set how thick the lines are.

The *Camera* socket of the *Texture Coordinates* node, sets the mapping to match the camera. Thus the grid will be straight.
The *Mix* node is used to overlay the grid over any shader you already have on the object. It works from the *Fac* output from the brick texture. white = 1, and black = 0 so where ever there is black in the grid it will use the bottom shader, and whereever there is white (where the bricks would go) it will use the top input of the *Mix shader*. The brown *Diffuse* node would be the underlying shader.

Those nodes will render this:
[image: render]

Comment: Nice! the camera option in the texture coordinate node didn't work for me...? any tips?

Comment: Thanks, but I can have them both in full opacity, not mixing the values in between, right?

Comment: the "usefull question" button doesn't work as a non registered user and I'm having trouble with registration, but I'll fix it or check "best answer". Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Vladimir the reason the up vote button wont work is because you do not have enough rep yet. You need 15 to up vote.

Comment: Just one thing - Does this requires a "uv project" modifier?

Comment: @Vladimir not at all. only 2 things are required to get the grid the Texture Coordinates node and the Brick texture node.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing - I did all of that, but the vertical edges are not aligned forming edge loops as they go from top to bottom. I get this - http://www.tripurple.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Red_Brick_Wall.jpg

How can I fix that?

Comment: @Vladimir that is already in my answer, set both Frequency fields to 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes(if I read your question correctly).
In this case I'm overlaying a <s>grid</s>(checker texture) as such:

[image]

You can use a image of a grid texture instead of the checker texture.

**Steps:**

1. Uv unwrap your mesh.
2. Add a uv project modifier.
   [image]
3. Set the projector to your camera.
   [image]
4. Set the Uv map to your Uv map
5. Set up a material such as this:

[image]

You can use any texture instead of the checker texture.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little new to blender. What is a "uv project modifier"?
What do you mean by "projector" and how can I set it to the camera?
And what do you mean with "Set the Uv map to your Uv map"? Basicly, I want to render an object with a checkered wireframe. Is that it?

Comment: Done, feel free to ask more questions!

Comment: the "usefull question" button doesn't work as a non registered user and I'm having trouble with registration, but I'll fix it or check "best answer". Thanks for the answer.