# Show banding on object

Tags: materials, node-editor, mathematics

I'd like to emphasisze the '3d-ness' of my object, by applying a rectangular mesh to it, as if it were a white object in a black room illuminated only by a (far away) laser that scans horizontal and vertical lines.

I manage to get as far as this picture:

[image: screenshot of my progress so far]

Now, instead of the 'black' lines, i would like them to be solid green. And instead of the green gradients, it would be nice if these would be black.

Conceptually, what I'm looking for (I think I am): I'd like to tell the node editor something like:

*if your input value is smaller then 0.9, output 0. If it is between 0.9 and 1, output 1.*

How do I achieve this?

I used the following setup of my nodes:

[image: material node setup]

My question looks a bit like: [How to make a mesh look like it was 3D printed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/how-to-make-a-mesh-look-like-it-was-3d-printed)

Comment: perhaps of interest: [making-a-laser-in-cycles-straight-beam-of-light](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/making-a-laser-in-cycles-straight-beam-of-light)

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14394/599. Though I'd recommend zeffii's suggestion of actually illuminating the object with lights as you describe. After all, you have a light simulation engine. Why not use it? ;)

Comment: That does the trick! Never thought of using the brick shader for this.

Comment: @gandalf3 Would you mind turning your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here's a grid OSL shader I wrote a while back.

```
/*
  Grid Lines 
  : Author Dealga McArdle, 2013
  : modified from Sine Stripes by Thomas Dinges

  example shaders:
  http://www.openshading.com/osl/example-shaders/

*/

#include "stdosl.h"

shader GridShaderUV(

    // input and output parameters
    vector Vector = P,
    color GridColor = color(0.8),
    float Intensity = 1.0,
    float Distance_U = 0.02,
    float Distance_V = 0.02,
    int Stripes_U = 10,
    int Stripes_V = 10,        
    output float Fac = 1.0,
    output color Color = color(0.8),
    float World_X = 1.0,
    float World_Y = 1.0
    )
{

    // shader code
    point Pos = Vector;
    Pos[0] -= World_X;
    float pattern_col = 0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < Stripes_U; ++i ) {
        Pos[0] += Distance_U;
        pattern_col += abs(Intensity / Pos[0] / 1000.0);
    }

    Pos = Vector;
    Pos[1] -= World_Y;    
    for(int i = 0; i < Stripes_V; ++i ) {
        Pos[1] += Distance_V;
        pattern_col += abs(Intensity / Pos[1] / 1000.0);
    }    

    color C = transformc("hsv", GridColor);

    Fac = pattern_col;
    Color = color("hsv", C[0], C[1], (Fac*C[2]));
}
```

It generates a grid of black vs some user defined colour. There are many ways to use it, but to get a feel for it I suggest sticking it as a material on a Plane, and see what the sliders do.

If you add a Suzanne, you could set the Stripes U and V to 1 so there's only one grid line, then animate the Distance X between the extents of your object., and you'll get the laser scan effect. Or animate the WORLD X,Y as they are the center of the shader's coordinate system.

[image]

[image]

Looks like this

[image]

It's a grid osl, therefore capable (and intended) to make grids.

[image]

#### Alternatively, xyz banding

remove the axis you don't need. You can offset the Geometry position by some vector amount if the missing Axis band (0,0,0) bothers you

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's extremely cool!

Comment: Yeah, too many solutions for some problems :)

Comment: I like the last answer the most. I used it my own answer, although I marked yours as THE answer. √

Answer (score 6):

This is how it looks after using @gandalf3 suggestion: (bricks)

[image]

And here's a screenshot using @zeffii answer, which I marked as "THE" answer, because it elaborated on my own, initial approach. I include it in my answer, because I changed some settings in the nodes that might be of interest to others:

[image]

Changes:

1. turn 'less than' into 'Greater than'.
2. Add the X, Y and Z into one value and put this into a CombineRGB --> only green lines
3. There are two 'value' nodes in the original answer. I combined the into one,
   where I calculate the value of the second from the first one.