# Wireframe horizontal vertices - retro video game effect

Tags: wireframe

How am I able to recreate this effect? I have used the wireframe modifier to utilise the crossing mesh on existing models but would love to be able to only have a horizontal vertices that hide the vertices behind to create the shape.

[image: Horizontal vertices]

Comment: what render ending are you looking to do this in?

Comment: Possibly related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30542/show-banding-on-object

Answer (score 2):

In your *Wireframe Modifier*, uncheck *Replace Original*. Up the *Material:* value to 1.

Go to the *Materials tab*. Make sure you have two material slots, the top being black and the bottom being green.

This will make it so that you have something black in between the green lines to stop light from the hidden green lines getting through.

*Jimmy Gunawan's [image](http://blendersushi.blogspot.com/2014/03/modeling-ultimate-wireframe-modifier.html?m=1); cropped and modified:*

[image]

*Blender Nerd's image from his YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-ZC155hC7Q); cropped:*

[image]

*A gif I created:*

[image]

Check out the gif's .blend file!

[image]

Comment: Can you show a result please? Does it work in cycles too?

Comment: It's meant for cycles. Just excuse the screenshots. See the gif. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: I am not the OP. I like your answer. I wish you had reproduced the terrain/topography of the original question in your answer, so people can compare the two and see the results produced by your solution, as the gif does not present only horizontal lines showing.

Comment: Yeah I can do that effect with wireframe on all the edges, but looking for a solution to do the horizontal lines like in my initial question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the material [explained here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30545/935) I setup the striping to control the mix of a diffuse and emission to get the following result.

[image: striped hills]

using these nodes

[image: striped nodes]

[image]